# how can i get the insert_id using prepare statement in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I tried but I can't get insert_id from the function. I have made a class call functions but I don't understand how can I get it. See below code.

```
class DatabaseConnection {
protected $pdo;
public function __construct() {
 try {
   $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx', 'root', '');
 } catch(PDOException $e) {
  exit('Database error');
  }
 }
}

class Invoice extends DatabaseConnection {
  public function order($rename, $location) {
  $query = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO orderlist (re_name, location) VALUES (?, ?)");
  $query -> execute(array($rename, $location));
}

$user = new Invoice();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   $rename = $_POST['re_name'];
   $location = $_POST['location'];
   $insertOrder  = $user->order($rename, $location); // call the function here
   $insertid = ____ // I want to get id using insert_id in here see blank space.
}
```

Data is inserted successfully but how can I get id which I insert data recently. help me.

Comment: is your id auto increment field?

Comment: call insert_id after  execute
$pstm->execute();
$pstm->insert_id;

Comment: yes. My id is auto increment field.

Comment: you can use max() to get the last inserted id

Comment: can I get the id from outside function?

Comment: it is an SQL function.

Comment: `$this->pdo->lastInsertId();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it work if you tried :

```
$user->getPdo->lastInsertId();
```

[Details](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: It works. Thank you so much.